# If else loop in r markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Hi Have a data frame generated from a calculation. This dataframe will have results from other calculations and finally it will have something like this.

Minimum working code

````
```{r echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, } 
        cond_a <- c(1,2,3,4)
        cond_b <- c("a","v","b","c")
        reminder <- c(3,4,6,7)
        Diff <- c(0,1,0,0)
        df = data.frame(cond_a, cond_b, reminder, Diff)       # df is a data frame
        df$Result <- ifelse(df$Diff !=0, "FAIL", "PASS")
        Test_Results <- subset(df, Diff != 0)

```
````

After the dataframe is generated, I am putting this whole thing in a R markdown document and want to print it in a way that if the dataframe has 0 rows, then I want to Print- "Test case passed", if dataframe has some rows(i.e failed records), then I want to print the dataframe.

````
```{r echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, }
    if {nrow(Test_Results) = 0
    print("Test case Passed")}
    else {
     DT::datatable(Test_Results)  
    }
```
````

So far, I am not able to produce expected results. any help please.

Comment: Check for equality with `==` rather than `=` and get the brackets right (`if (nrow(Test_Results) == 0) {`, and then it all appears to work fine.

Comment: You are right sir, it is working fine. Thanks a lot for figuring it out. I am not sure how to accept comment as acceptable answer,